# Google Sheet importxml for Price

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get prices on this site, but it's always NA.

https://id.xiapibuy.com/product/51925611/16618169044

Please help me check , thanks!

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/font/font")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUJFu.png)

Comment: Check if that xpath is the correct one on your broswer. Also, what error does say when you hover the cursor onthe C3 cell? - check also if the data you want to get is embed in the HTML itself or if it's added with JS.

Answer (score 0):

if you disable JavaScript on the given URL you can see the page is empty

[image]

google sheets is not able to work with / import JS content